# Java make HTTP call to AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, httpclient

I have set up in AWS a private API gateway, I can call it use curl like this to access it:

```
curl -v https://vpce-02e21f9af4f10cf2a-6y6qzepe-ap-southeast-2b.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.vpce.amazonaws.com/Test/uppercase/zzzddd -H'Host:515btqa443.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com'
```

I can also use Postman by set the URL and set the header.

However, I seem to have an issue accessing it from Java, I think it is not adding the Header and I get 403 forbidden message.

```
String urlstr = "https://vpce-02e21f9af4f10cf2a-6y6qzepe-ap- 
southeast-2b.execute-api.ap-southeast- 
2.vpce.amazonaws.com/Test/uppercase/zzzddd";
URL url = new URL(urlstr);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) 
url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.addRequestProperty("Host", "515btqa443.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com");
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
```

Any ideas if i am doing something wrong in the Java ?

Comment: I doubt it, but maybe try setting a user agent to be something else? __Maybe__ it's blocking the default user agent?

Comment: Can you include the trace output from curl?